# How to call function in extented .js file, from <body> with tag div or other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In head I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/categ.js"></script>
```

In categ.js, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gallery=new sim({
    wrapperid: "gallery1"

..................
</script>
```

In body I have:

```
<div id="gallery1"></div>
```

When I load page, the script is not called, because is in extended file. If I paste it directly in head - it's works.

So, How I can call from "body" with some tag the function in categ.js

Comment: Can you clarify what the gallery object should be doing? For example, is the object supposed to modify the appearance of the #gallery1 div in your body segment.

Comment: Nope, nothing to modif. I just want to call it from extended file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
...
</script>
```

inside the **categ.js** file.

---

Then put:

```
window.onload = function() {
 // the JS code you want to execute
};
```

in the file. If you use **jQuery** you can replace this with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 // the JS code you want to execute
};
```

So in case you want to create a new object on page load you execute this code:

```
var gallery=new sim({
 wrapperid: "gallery1",
 foo : "bar"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling it with `window.onload` to ensure it runs on page ready:

```
window.onload = gallery;
```

Comment: Where I have to put it? In Body, between the div?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your tag is ready for using with your js by calling window.onload or use jquery